# Customize Asp.Net Identity 2.2.1 MVC 5 to use my existing users table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have my existing database with users table which has usernames and password. I want to use the same tables with asp.net Identity in MVC 5 instead of the Identity module creating AspNetusers and AspNetroles table for me.

Any insights would be of great help. Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to work this out?  I am in the process of gathering the required info and getting a solution working today will post an answer if I managed to create a working solution

Comment: I have something similar where I added fake users to the ASPusers table and login does not find them

Comment: @transformer thats because of the hasing mechanism